# How to scrape entire integer in python with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Working on getting some wave heights from websites and my code fails when the wave heights get into the double digit range.

Ex: Currently the code would scrape a 12 from the site as '1' and '2' separately, not '12'.

```
#Author: David Owens
#File name: soupScraper.py
#Description: html scraper that takes surf reports from various websites

import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

NUM_SITES = 2

reportsFinal = []

###################### SURFLINE URL STRINGS AND TAG ###########################

slRootUrl = 'http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/'
slSunsetCliffs = 'sunset-cliffs-southern-california_4254/'
slScrippsUrl = 'scripps-southern-california_4246/'
slBlacksUrl = 'blacks-southern-california_4245/'
slCardiffUrl = 'cardiff-southern-california_4786/'

slTagText = 'observed-wave-range'
slTag = 'id'

#list of surfline URL endings
slUrls = [slSunsetCliffs, slScrippsUrl, slBlacksUrl]

###############################################################################


#################### MAGICSEAWEED URL STRINGS AND TAG #########################

msRootUrl = 'http://magicseaweed.com/'
msSunsetCliffs = 'Sunset-Cliffs-Surf-Report/4211/'
msScrippsUrl = 'Scripps-Pier-La-Jolla-Surf-Report/296/'
msBlacksUrl = 'Torrey-Pines-Blacks-Beach-Surf-Report/295/'

msTagText = 'rating-text'
msTag = 'li'

#list of magicseaweed URL endings
msUrls = [msSunsetCliffs, msScrippsUrl, msBlacksUrl]

###############################################################################

'''
This class represents a surf break. It contains all wave, wind, & tide data 
associated with that break relevant to the website
'''
class surfBreak:
    def __init__(self, name,low, high, wind, tide):
        self.name = name
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.wind = wind
        self.tide = tide    

    #toString method    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}: Wave height: {1}-{2} Wind: {3} Tide: {4}'.format(self.name, 
            self.low, self.high, self.wind, self.tide)
#END CLASS

'''
This returns the proper attribute from the surf report sites
'''
def reportTagFilter(tag):
    return (tag.has_attr('class') and 'rating-text' in tag['class']) \
        or (tag.has_attr('id') and tag['id'] == 'observed-wave-range')
#END METHOD

'''
This method checks if the parameter is of type int
'''
def representsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True

    except ValueError:
        return False
#END METHOD

'''
This method extracts all ints from a list of reports

reports: The list of surf reports from a single website

returns: reportNums - A list of ints of the wave heights
'''
def extractInts(reports):
    print reports
    reportNums = []
    afterDash = False
    num = 0
    tens = 0
    ones = 0

    #extract all ints from the reports and ditch the rest 
    for report in reports:
        for char in report:
            if representsInt(char) == True:

                num = int(char)                 
                reportNums.append(num)

            else:
                afterDash = True

    return reportNums
#END METHOD

'''
This method iterates through a list of urls and extracts the surf report from
the webpage dependent upon its tag location

rootUrl: The root url of each surf website
urlList: A list of specific urls to be appended to the root url for each 
         break

tag:     the html tag where the actual report lives on the page

returns: a list of strings of each breaks surf report
'''
def extractReports(rootUrl, urlList, tag, tagText):
    #empty list to hold reports
    reports = []
    reportNums = []
    index = 0

    #loop thru URLs
    for url in urlList:
        try:
            index += 1
            #request page
            request = requests.get(rootUrl + url)

            #turn into soup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'lxml')

            #get the tag where surflines report lives
            reportTag = soup.findAll(reportTagFilter)[0]

            reports.append(reportTag.text.strip())      

        #notify if fail 
        except:
            print 'scrape failure at URL ', index
            pass

    reportNums = extractInts(reports)

    return reportNums
#END METHOD

'''
This method calculates the average of the wave heights
'''
def calcAverages(reportList):
    #empty list to hold averages
    finalAverages = []
    listIndex = 0
    waveIndex = 0

    #loop thru list of reports to calc each breaks ave low and high
    for x in range(0, 6):
            #get low ave
            average = (reportList[listIndex][waveIndex] 
                + reportList[listIndex+1][waveIndex]) / NUM_SITES

            finalAverages.append(average)

            waveIndex += 1

    return finalAverages
#END METHOD

slReports = extractReports(slRootUrl, slUrls, slTag, slTagText)
msReports = extractReports(msRootUrl, msUrls, msTag, msTagText)

reportsFinal.append(slReports)
reportsFinal.append(msReports)

print 'Surfline:     ', slReports
print 'Magicseaweed: ', msReports
```

Comment: So what you are _actually_ asking is why your `extract_ints` parses the values incorrectly? That would be your actual [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since the data itself seems to get scraped correctly from the website.

Comment: @TeemuRisikko I thought it scraped the entire HTML element, which is why i have the extract ints to parse through it.

Comment: Yes it does parse the entire element, but beyond that (and because of that) it kinda has nothing to do with beautifulsoup anymore, because bs cannot parse it further like you said. Just semantics but it is always  good to know the root problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually extracting integers, but floats, it seems, since the values in `reports` are something like `['0.3-0.6 m']`. Right now you are just going through every single character and converting them to int one by one or discarding. So no wonder that you will get only single-digit numbers.

One (arguably) simple way to extract those numbers from that string is with regexp:

```
import re

FLOATEXPR = re.compile("(\d+\.\d)-(\d+\.\d) {0,1}m")

def extractFloats(reports):
    reportNums = []
    for report in reports:
        groups = re.match(FLOATEXPR, report).groups()
        for group in groups:
            reportNums.append(float(group))
    return reportNums
```

This expression would match your floats and return them as a list.

In detail, the expression will match anything that has at least one digit before a `'.'`, and one digit after it, a `'-'` between, another float sequence and ending with `'m'` or `' m'`. Then it groups the parts representing floats to a tuple. For example that `['12.0m-3.0m']` would return `[12.0, 3.0]`. If you expect it to have more digits after the floating point, you can add an extra `'+'` after the second `'d'`:s in the expression.